# django: extending user model with one-to-one link - how to use post_save signal

Tags: django

I am new to django , I am learning how to extend the user model using the following site: 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

I have some doubt in the following model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

How this line exactly works:

```
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I know post_save will be called after user is created, but I don't understand how the following line is used to store the additional fields.

```
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: It isn't. It only creates a blank profile for the current user.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, thank you very much, Now I understand